# What happen when I use Vector.erase(), Is there something wrong or I got some mistake

Tags: vector, stl

I've just tried some STL, and I got a problem, I couldn't explain how it worked like that.
    I have some code below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<int> myvector(3,20);
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    myvector.push_back(12);
    myvector.push_back(15);

    int i = 0;
    for(it = myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); it++)
    {
        if(*it==20)
        {
            cout<<"delete "<<i<<endl;

            myvector.erase(it);
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(it = myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); it++)
        cout<<*it<<"  ";
```

vector.erase() didn't erase the third item ('20' in my vector), it print out : 20 12 15
but I think I should be : 12 15.

so, any one can explain how it work for me or I got some mistake any where ?
thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an item in a STL container using iterators, any previous iterators become invalid.  So after myvector.erase(it), it is no longer valid.  To address this, erase returns a new iterator, pointing to the next element.  So your code should be:

```
for(it = myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); )
{
    if(*it==20)
    {
        cout<<"delete "<<i<<endl;

        it = myvector.erase(it);
    } else {
        it++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

I also only increment it in the loop.  That way, when you erase you don't jump an extra element forward.

Comment: `i` and `it` are two different things. Otherwise your explanation is good.

Comment: Thanks for notice me that it is a pointer, I didn't remmember that
btw,'i' just a variable, which I want to check where the member of vector will be erase, not 'it', so it should be : it++;

Comment: Ah, when I was quickly scanning the code I misread i as it.  I've updated my answer appropriately.